# UWP _isInBackgroundMode

Tags: c#, uwp

I am having a problem with my code.

Says the value is set, but not used...

I get the nice green line under bool _isInBackgroundMode = false;

What am I not getting here?

```
namespace MyApp
{
using Views;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;

sealed partial class App : Application
{
    bool _isInBackgroundMode = false;

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

        this.EnteredBackground += App_EnteredBackground;
        this.LeavingBackground += App_LeavingBackground;

    }

    private void App_EnteredBackground(object sender, EnteredBackgroundEventArgs e)
    {
        _isInBackgroundMode = true;
    }

    private void App_LeavingBackground(object sender, LeavingBackgroundEventArgs e)
    {
        _isInBackgroundMode = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you don't have any code reading that value.  As of now; or at least what you've shown; you are only setting the value and no where is it actually used (read from).

Once you write code that says something like

```
if (_isInBackgroundMode)
    doSomething();
```

Then the green line will go away.

Comment: The documentation says I need to set bool _isInBackgroundMode = false; so I can toggle it with my private voids... I am also looking at examples and this is what they do in them, even in the official samples..  There is not too much info or examples showing usage on this.. Not even sure what to put as the dosomething() because what I am doing is in the private voids and I have seen no examples doing this.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  What method or object is using the _isInBackgroundMode field?  Just because you set the field doesn't mean it's used.  Unless there is some underlying framework accessing the field, but then it would probably already exist.  You're making a new field and if it's not used then you're getting that info warning.  Just because you set that field doesn't mean it does anything.

Comment: This is the documentation I used... Maybe you can make heads and tails out of it better than I can.. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio)

Comment: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio)

Comment: Yeap.. In your current code it isn't used so you get that info warning.  That is just so you have a variable to look at to determine if you're in the background or not when doing other operations.  Look at this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/reduce-memory-usage) and on the 5th block of code examples, it shows them checking the isInBackgroundMode field to determine whether or not to reduce the memory.  In other words, you can call it whatever you want but it's just an easy way to track whether you're in the background or not for other areas of the application.

Comment: Once you have written some code that relies on the isInBackgroundMode field as a check (reads from it) then the green info warning will go away.  To test just put that if statement anywhere in the code and you'll see.

Comment: I think I get it a little more now.. I just have to figure out how to get this to sing with my appshell...window.current does not play well with my app. My navigation is based on this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlNavigation/cs)

Comment: appshell shell = window.current.content Thanks for the pointer.. I think I might be able to get this working now..